# GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl) returns null but I have no idea what I'm missing

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am trying to implement an Identity Server Solution that redirects the user to different Login Views depending on the client application they come from.

To do this, in the `AccountController.cs` file I have the following method:

```cs
 private async Task<LoginViewModel> BuildLoginViewModelAsync(string returnUrl)
        {
            var isValid = this.interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(returnUrl);
            var context = await this.interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
            var schemes = await this.schemeProvider.GetAllSchemesAsync();

            return new LoginViewModel
            {
                AllowRememberLogin = AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin,
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
                Username = context?.LoginHint
            };
        }
```

I have set up a Configuration & Operational DbContexts as per [this](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html) tutorial from the IdentityServer4 documentation.

Additionally, I have seeded the database with some rows in the `Clients` & `ClientRedirectUris` tables.

Presumably, that should be all I need to access the AuthorizationContext from the IIdentityServerInteractionService API, but the method above always returns null, and the `isValid` variable is always false too.

I have made sure that the `returnUrl` I am passing in is exactly the same as the redirectUri stored in my database (I am using localhost and running all this locally, if that matters)

Can someone please help? I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: what is your return URL?

Comment: @nahidf It is `http://localhost:4200/callback`, and I have also tried a bunch of different combinations, removed slashes, I've even tried simple existing website links like `https://www.google.com/`, etc. 

I thought maybe IdSrv4 wasn't grabbing the Clients I've set up properly, but if that is the case I still see no reason why the `IsValidReturnUrl()` API call would be false too...

Comment: The valid return url is `/callback`, check this code which validate the return URL https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Services/Default/OidcReturnUrlParser.cs#L60 This is default parser though, you can add your own parser. And here is check for local URL https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Extensions/StringsExtensions.cs#L147 . What I try to say is that your URL is not valid per this code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this:

```
Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new {ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] })


[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model, string ReturnUrl) {
...
}
```